# How to: make my code more efficient in R by not creating new dataframes repeatedly?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, text-mining

Problem:

Firstly, I am just starting out. While I was proud of my code, I have realised how inefficient and non-replicable it is coming back to it and using it on a different variable. Particularly, #3) has a manual component when excluding columns (downpour, precipitation, rainwater) which is not very replicable. Could anyone advise? (it looked worse before if you can believe)

Code:

```
# 1) filter for dictionaries containing 1,000 noun counts or more 
  f1_raincount <- raincount %>% filter(total_ncount >= 1000)

# 2) filter for dictionaries which contain 3 or more tokens from our set of rain-related tokens 
  f2_raincount <- f1_raincount
  #compute rain-set count 
  f2_raincount$set_count <- f2_raincount %>% select(cloud:thunderstorm) %>% apply(1, function(x) sum(x != 0, values_drop_na=TRUE))
  f2_raincount <- f2_raincount %>% filter(set_count >= 3) 

# 3) Select for rain-related noun tokens with frequencies greater than 10 across dictionaries 
  #First, compute dictionary counts 
  f3_raincount <- f2_raincount
  f3_dict_long <- f3_raincount %>% select(cloud:thunderstorm) %>% apply(2, function(x) sum(x !=0)) 
  #Second, exclude those under 10: downpour, precipitation, rainwater
  f3_raincount <- f3_raincount %>% select(-c(downpour, precipitation, rainwater) ) 

# 4) given exclusion #3, compute rain set count and filter again 
  f4_raincount <- f3_raincount
  f4_raincount$set_count2 <- f4_raincount %>% select(cloud:thunderstorm) %>% apply(1, function(x) sum(x != 0))
  f4_raincount <- f4_raincount %>% filter(set_count2 >= 3) %>% 
    select(id:dictsize) #select final rain-set
```

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is have all ETL code inside a ETL function even if i only plan to run it once on the entire script.

why?

1. Find it easy to debug if errors arise with debug
2. While on the topic of debuging, it's easier to debug also because the enviroment will only contain the used variables and not everything else
3. Auxiliar variables are automatically deleted once the function call is over
4. Easier to document that chunk of code with a title
5. More reproducible

because of this my scripts tend to be 20% setting parameters and libraries
60% functions and 20% code that runs those functions

your final code should then look like this:

```
f4_raincount <- funcName(raincount)
```

naturally having all the other messy code inside funcName

As for the actual code I'd need an actual example (data table and libraries) since it looks to me that you are just adding count columns that could be done with mutate function from dplyr. If that is indeed the case then you have a lot of optimization in front of you :P. but not knowing what cloud:thunderstorm is it's hard to give you more feedback.

EDIT:

ETL (Extract Transform Load) might not have been a good idea for me to mention since we are only Transforming data and neither Extracting or Loading.

Either way, I belive it's best if I demonstrate on a chunk of code.
Imagine we have a dataframe df.MyData and want to calculate the ratio between 2 variables times a certain ratio (just becaue)

Here's how one might approach this simple problem:

```
library(dplyr)
df.MyData <- data.frame(#this is of course a bad idea, But since a real world example would make this unreproducible code I went with it anyway.
    Group = c("A","A","B","B","B"),
    Value = c(1,3,1,4,5)
)
n.Value_A <- sum(filter(df.MyData, Group == "A")$Value)
n.Value_B <- sum(filter(df.MyData, Group == "B")$Value)
n.Result <- n.Value_A / n.Value_B * pf.n.Ratio
```

Here's how I would do it:

```
# LIBRARY ####
    library(dplyr)
# PARAMETERS ####
    df.MyData <- data.frame(#this is of course a bad idea, But since a real world example would make this unreproducible code I went with it anyway.
            Group = c("A","A","B","B","B"),
            Value = c(1,3,1,4,5)
        )
# FUNCTIONS ####
    fn.CalculateRatio <- function(pf.df.MyData = df.MyData, pf.n.Ratio = 2)
    {
        n.Value_A <- sum(filter(df.MyData, Group == "A")$Value)
        n.Value_B <- sum(filter(df.MyData, Group == "B")$Value)
        n.Result <- n.Value_A / n.Value_B * pf.n.Ratio
        return(n.Result)
    }
# PROCESS ####
    fn.CalculateRatio()
```

My approach clearly has more code, so it very well might be disregarded by many, but I prefer it nonetheless as I tend to find it more organized on bigger pieces of code.

Your example would look like this:

```
fn.MyFunc <- function(pf.raincount = raincount){
    # 1) filter for dictionaries containing 1,000 noun counts or more 
        f1_raincount <- pf.raincount %>% filter(total_ncount >= 1000)
    .......[your code (excluding first 2 rows) goes here]
    return(f4_raincount)
}

fn.MyFunc()
```

You could naturally go the extra mile, and replace the mention of (what looks like arbitrary numbers) `1000` and `3` by other variables and place them on the function itself. This way, should you want to change them you simply need to explicitly mention the value you want to use when running the function

```
fn.MyFunc(pf.raincount = NEWraincount)
```

or something else if you define other variables

I'm using prefixes on all my variables to identify what they are `fn` for functions, `df` for data frames, `pf` for function parameters, `n` for length 1 number vectors... the list is quite extensive, and I go as far as having a rulebook with all the rules that I use to stay consistent across projects but that's also a story for another day
Finally, I find `# XXXXXX ####` very useful as I can hide chunks of code when I'm not working on them

Again this is how I find organization on hundreds or thousands of lines of code. Each one of us has to figure his own style, the only thing I believe we all agree with, is that consistency is key.

I'm straining a bit of topic though, the key idea of using this wrapper function is that the other tables you define stay inside the function environment and get deleted afterwards. It's better to actually edit the code to not create them in the first place, but at the least you can use this method as a bandage since it takes close to no time or skill to clean those variables (I didn't have to understand your code to make this post)

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback @user13900375!

3. I am realising I have made a big mistake in not creating auxiliary variables which are automatically deleted once the function call is over--not sure how to remedy this now. 

These are the libraries:

Comment: 1. May I ask what an ETL function is, which I am guessing corresponds to 'funcName'?   

library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(here)    

cloud to thunderstorm are columns which consist of counts for those words in 1067 dictionaries. In the code, I am applying exclusion criteria to a sample of words which brings 16 words down to 13 and eliminates rows in the data frame.    

This is how the data frame looks (with variables included above):
id, cloud, clouds, drizzle, hail, mist, monsoon, rain, rainbow, rainfall, rains, sleet, storm, thunderstorm, dictsize

Comment: @n.baes I've edited my answer. It's a lot larger now, but it should also be clear what I mean